# How to mount USB device on OSX while sleeping?

Tags: python, macos, usb, sleep, mount

Usually USB devices are mounted when the computer is awake.I am writing a program to awake the computer with a USB device but the computer does not recognize the USB device while sleeping.How can I solve this?

Comment: I am sure that OS X recognizes the USB device.It's UID and VID shows up in system_profiler but that's all.It does not mount up.

Comment: I think the terminology is off, which could be confusing.  You *mount* a filesystem, but *enumerate* a USB device.

Comment: It sounds like you're writing firmware for a USB device, right?  We're going to need a lot more information (and probably source code) to help you out here.  Normally the host should wake to enumerate devices at the time they're connected, so I suspect there's something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

you can not mount a device while sleeping because the sleep state is a either `SUSPEND_TO_MEMORY` or `SUSPEND_TO_DISK` in that not all functions of the machine are available ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode )

you can wakeup the machine over USB ( wake up event ). the principle of USB wakeup is similar to WOL ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN ). a special interupt is send to the host what triggers the host to wake up. not all USB devices are able to generate this interrupt, mass storage devices like USB sticks are not able, mice and keyboards and ... are ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537628(v=vs.85).aspx , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551766(v=vs.85).aspx ). maybe it is possible to emulate this interrupt with a USB mass storage device however then you have to modify the firmware of the device and this close to impossible if you do not develop your own mass storage device

in http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/220-ubuntu-resume-usb-hid is example for linux